# How to produce multiple output files with a single input file using the command 'np.random.normal'?

Tags: python, loops, numpy, random, normal-distribution

I have a file with 44,586 lines of data. It is read in using pylab:

```
data = pl.loadtxt("20100101.txt")
density = data[:,0]
```

I need to run something like...

```
densities = np.random.normal(density, 30, 1)
np.savetxt('1.txt', np.vstack((densities.ravel())).T)
```

...and create a new file named 1.txt which has all 44,586 lines of my data randomised within the parameters I desire. Will my above commands be sufficient to read through and perform what I want on every line of data?

The more complicated part on top of this - is that I want to run this 1,000 times and produce 1,000 .txt files (1.txt, 2.txt ... 1000.txt) which each run the exact same command.

I become stuck when trying to run loops in scripts, as I am still very inexperienced. I am having trouble even beginning to get this running how I desire - also I am confused how to handle saving the files with their different names. I have used np.savetxt in the past, but don't know how to make it perform this task.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: why not use for loop

Comment: Because I don't know how to apply it, this is why I am asking here.

Comment: could you provide sample of the input file

Comment: try something like for in range(1:1001):densities = np.random.normal(density, 30, 1)    np.savetxt(str(i)+'.txt', np.vstack((densities.ravel())).T)

Comment: Thank you. I will test this when I get to work tomorrow.
Oh, and the input file is just a single column of numbers with 46000 lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two minor issues - the first relates to how to select the name of the files (which can be solved using pythons support for string concatenation), the second relates to `np.random.normal` - which only allows a size parameter when loc is a scalar.

```
data = pl.loadtxt("20100101.txt") 
density = data[:,0]
for i in range(1, 1001):
    densities = np.random.normal(loc=density, scale=30)
    np.savetxt(str(i) + '.txt', densities)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will test this when I get to work tomorrow. It looks very simple, I wish I was able to come up with it myself.